# How to extend RecyclerView to allow "merging" of items?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, drag-and-drop, drag

I'm trying to implement "merging" of items using RecyclerView.

We have a a list of cards that you can scroll through, edit, and reorder. We also have the concept of "stacks" where you can combine cards into a stack. Previously you could only download preset stacks of content, but now I'm trying to implement custom stacks. See below for screenshot of cards "at rest":

[image: Screenshot of cards]

Implementing reordering was really easy - I just hooked into the `ItemTouchListener.Callback` to deal with picking up and dropping cards. However, I'm having a really hard time getting merging to work. The functionality is when you release a dragged card over another card, it should call some code elsewhere to merge those stacks/cards into a new stack.

Big-picture process for how I'm doing this:

1. Use `chooseDropTarget` to store a reference to the last card we were over
2. Use `onDraw` to destroy this reference if we're no longer over that card
3. Use `clearView`to merge the two stacks if they're still over each other when we release the card

It works, but the merging is very inconsistent. I think the issue is that `clearView` is called after *all* animations, which I think includes the return to position/move animation. So depending on how the threads interact, sometimes the cards will be over each other when that method is called, and sometimes they won't

I've attached code below, and any specific comments are welcome - especially if you think I'm almost there. But I guess I'm really looking for big picture design here. Am I on the right track?

```
public class CardStackMoveCallback extends ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback {

    public interface CardStackMoveContract {
        void onCardStackSelectedForMove(StackViewHolder stackViewHolder);
        void onCardStackFinishedWithMove(StackViewHolder stackViewHolder);
        void onCardStackMoved(StackViewHolder moved, int to);
        void onCardStacksMerged(StackViewHolder dragged, StackViewHolder target);
    }

    private static final String TAG = CardStackMoveCallback.class.getSimpleName();

    public static CardStackMoveCallback create(CardStackMoveContract adapter) {
        int dragFlags = ItemTouchHelper.UP | ItemTouchHelper.DOWN;

        CardStackMoveCallback callback = new CardStackMoveCallback(dragFlags, 0);
        callback.setAdapter(adapter);
        return callback;
    }

    private CardStackMoveContract mAdapter;
    private StackViewHolder mCurrentStackToMergeInto;

    private CardStackMoveCallback(int dragDirs, int swipeDirs) {
        super(dragDirs, swipeDirs);

        mCurrentStackToMergeInto = null;
    }

    private void setAdapter(CardStackMoveContract adapter) {
        mAdapter = adapter;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder,
                          @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof StackViewHolder) {
            mAdapter.onCardStackMoved((StackViewHolder) viewHolder, target.getAdapterPosition());
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLongPressDragEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSelectedChanged(@Nullable RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int actionState) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof  StackViewHolder) {
            mAdapter.onCardStackSelectedForMove((StackViewHolder) viewHolder);
        }

        super.onSelectedChanged(viewHolder, actionState);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearView(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        if (viewHolder instanceof  StackViewHolder) {
            StackViewHolder stackViewHolder = (StackViewHolder) viewHolder;
            Log.v(TAG, viewHolder + " & " + mCurrentStackToMergeInto + " intersect? " + viewHoldersIntersect(viewHolder, mCurrentStackToMergeInto));

            if (viewHoldersIntersect(stackViewHolder, mCurrentStackToMergeInto)) {
                mAdapter.onCardStacksMerged(stackViewHolder, mCurrentStackToMergeInto);
            } else {
                mAdapter.onCardStackFinishedWithMove(stackViewHolder);
            }
        }
        super.clearView(recyclerView, viewHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder chooseDropTarget(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder selected, @NonNull List<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> dropTargets, int curX, int curY) {
        Log.v(TAG, "selected: " + selected + "; dropTargets: " + dropTargets);
        StackViewHolder selectedStackViewHolder = (StackViewHolder) selected;

        if (mCurrentStackToMergeInto == null && !selectedStackViewHolder.isPrayerPack()) {
            Log.v(TAG, "mCurrentStackToMergeInto is null so we're checking for A NEW CONTENDER");
            for (RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder : dropTargets) {
                if (viewHolder instanceof StackViewHolder && viewHoldersIntersect(selected, viewHolder)) {
                    StackViewHolder toMergeWith = (StackViewHolder) viewHolder;

                    if (!toMergeWith.isPrayerPack()) {
                        mCurrentStackToMergeInto = toMergeWith;
                        selectedStackViewHolder.startMerge();
                        mCurrentStackToMergeInto.startMergeInto();
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }
        }

        return super.chooseDropTarget(selected, dropTargets, curX, curY);
    }

    @Override
    public void onChildDraw(@NonNull Canvas c, @NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, float dX, float dY, int actionState, boolean isCurrentlyActive) {
        super.onChildDraw(c, recyclerView, viewHolder, dX, dY, actionState, isCurrentlyActive);

        if (mCurrentStackToMergeInto != null && !viewHoldersIntersect(viewHolder, mCurrentStackToMergeInto)) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Merge cancelled");
            StackViewHolder dragged = (StackViewHolder) viewHolder;
            dragged.cancelMerge();
            mCurrentStackToMergeInto.cancelMergingInto();
            mCurrentStackToMergeInto = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) { }

    @Override
    public boolean isItemViewSwipeEnabled() {
        return false;
    }

    private boolean viewHoldersIntersect(RecyclerView.ViewHolder dragged, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
        if (target == null) {
            return false;
        }

        Rect draggedRect = new Rect();
        Rect targetRect = new Rect();
        dragged.itemView.getHitRect(draggedRect);
        target.itemView.getHitRect(targetRect);
        Log.v(TAG, "draggedRect: " + draggedRect + "; targetRect: " + targetRect);

        return Rect.intersects(draggedRect, targetRect);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I never managed to solve this @Megamozg